# ORM em Python semelhantes ao do Django

Tags: python, django, orm

Eu estudei um bom tempo o framework `Django` e achei que o `ORM` do mesmo era excelente.

Tive a ideia, em algum momento, de montar uma aplicação com outro framework chamado `Flask`, utilizando um framework semelhante ao `Django`.

Eu pesquisei, porém não consegui encontrar muita coisa.

Gostaria de saber duas coisas:

- Existe algum framework para banco de dados (ORM) semelhante ao ORM do `Django`?
- É possível usar o framework do `Django`, sem depender especificamente de todo o framework ser instalado (instalar apenas o pacote referente ao ORM do Django, digo)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Existe algum framework para banco de dados (ORM) semelhante ao ORM do Django?

Sim, chama [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

[Ele tem uma versão para Flask](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/).

> É possível usar o framework do Django, sem depender especificamente de todo o framework ser instalado (instalar apenas o pacote referente ao ORM do Django, digo)?

[Aparentemente, sim](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-orm/).

Comment: Nesse caso, prefiro a `ORM` do Django +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Eu nunca usei o SQLAlchemy, mas muita gente me recomendou, ele parece ser superior ao do Django em diversos aspectos (mas isso é relativo, sobretudo pela sua familiaridade prévia com o Django). Se você só quer o ORM, talvez compense dar uma olhada nele como alternativa. P.S. Todos os links pra esse `django-orm` no site pypi estão quebrados, acho que esse projeto foi descontinuado... (mas continua sendo possível usar partes do Django e ignorar outras)

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr. Vejo que é um "entendedor" do Python :)

Comment: Prefira o SQLAlchemy -  o Django sempre foi feito de forma muito integrada - e basta ler um parágrafo da descrição do Djano-ORM publicado de forma independente no link acima, para perceber que não é um trabalho feito por uma comunidade grande - e sim, algo mais experimental sendo tocado principalmente por um único desenvolvedor. (veja pro exemplo, que ele só suporta um tipo de banco de dados)

Comment: O SQLAlchemy, por outro lado, é um ORM com mais de 10 anos de estrada, com uma vasta comunidade, e o pacote de 'ponte' - flask-SQLAlchemy em si mesmo é praticamente uma parte oficial do Flask, com a atenção de dezenas de desenvolvedores, e muitos e muitos exemplos em toda documentação sobre Flask existente - algo miuto mais interessante para se ter em produção.